# How to increase the size of the button of a short code of third party widget. below is the code

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, height

It needs to be placed on header section (revolution Slider - WP)

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the Book Appointment to render. -->
 <div class="lybrate-widget" identifier="/wgt/clinic/avis-hospital-sexual-medicine-and-mental-health-clinic"></div>
 <span class="lybrate-powered">Powered by <a target="_blank" href="https://www.lybrate.com">Lybrate.com</a></span>
<!-- Place this tag just before the <body> tag. -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.lybrate.com/js/v104/widget/root.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Revolution Slider -> Edit Slides and edit required slide (with buttons). Then click on button and specify Max Width and White Space values. Here an example:
[Screenshot from revolution slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIobt.png)

Comment: actually i need to add a shortcode in that. It is not executing

Comment: Can you please share your short code and the version of revolution slider you are using?

Comment: <!-- Place this tag where you want the Book Appointment to render. -->
 <div class="lybrate-widget" identifier="/wgt/clinic/avis-hospital-sexual-medicine-and-mental-health-clinic"></div>
 <span class="lybrate-powered">Powered by <a target="_blank" href="https://www.lybrate.com">Lybrate.com</a></span>
<!-- Place this tag just before the <body> tag. -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.lybrate.com/js/v104/widget/root.js"></script>

Comment: Above is the short code that needs to be inserted, It results a button with link. So I want that button to big in size in Slider.                                        Revolution Slider version is 5.3                                                                    Thanks :)

Comment: You can use css to change the size of button.
for example-
.class /* Widget class name for button*/
{
 width: /*define your width*/;
height: /*define your height*/;
}